# Network Streams - Amount to read per Read

Tags: c#, networking, stream, byte

Im currently a bit stuck with my c# project.

I have 2 applications, they both have a common class definition I call a NetMessage

a NetMessage contains a MessageType string property, as well as 2 List lists.
The idea is that I can pack this class with classes, and data to send across the network as a byte[].

Because Network Streams do not advertise the amount of data they are receiving, I modified my Send method to send the size of the NetMessage byte[] ahead of the actual byte[].

```
private static byte[] ReceivedBytes(NetworkStream MainStream)
    {
        try
        {
            //byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int receivedDataLength = 0;
            byte[] data = { };
            long len = 0;
            int i = 0;
            MainStream.ReadTimeout = 60000;
            //MainStream.CanTimeout = false;
            if (MainStream.CanRead)
            {
                //Read  the length of the incoming message
                byte[] byteLen = new byte[8];
                MainStream.Read(byteLen, 0, 8);
                len = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteLen, 0);
                data = new byte[len];

                //data is now set to the appropriate size for the expected message
                //While we have not got the full message
                //Read each individual byte and append to data.
                //This method, seems to work, but is ridiculously slow,

                while (receivedDataLength < data.Length)
                {
                    receivedDataLength += MainStream.Read(data, receivedDataLength, 1);
                }
                //receivedDataLength += MainStream.Read(data, receivedDataLength, data.Length);
                return data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception:" + E.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have tried to change the size argument below to something like 1024 or to be the data.Length, but I get funky results.
receivedDataLength += MainStream.Read(data, receivedDataLength, 1);

setting it to data.Length seems to cause problems when the Class being sent is a few mb in size.
Setting the buffer size to be 1024 like I have seen in other examples, causes failures when the size of the incoming message is small, like 843 bytes, it errors out saying that I tried to read out of bounds or something.

Below is the type of method being used to send the data in the first place.

```
public static void SendBytesToStream(NetworkStream TheStream, byte[] TheMessage)
    {

        //IAsyncResult r = TheStream.BeginWrite(TheMessage, 0, TheMessage.Length, null, null);
        // r.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
        //TheStream.EndWrite(r); 
        try
        {
            long len = TheMessage.Length;

            byte[] Bytelen = BitConverter.GetBytes(len);

            TheStream.Write(Bytelen, 0, Bytelen.Length);
            TheStream.Flush();
            // <-- I've tried putting thread sleeps in this spot to see if it helps
            //I've also tried writing each byte of the message individually
            //takes longer, but seems more accurate as far as network transmission goes?
            TheStream.Write(TheMessage, 0, TheMessage.Length);
            TheStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'd like to get these two methods setup to the point where they are reliably sending and receiving data.
The application I am using this for, monitors a screenshots folder in a game directory,
when it detects a screenshot in TGA format, it converts it to PNG, then takes its byte[] and sends it to the receiver.
The receiver then posts it to Facebook (I don't want my FB tokens distributed in my client application), hence the server / proxy idea.
Its strange, but when I step through the code, the transfer is invariably successful.
But if I run it full speed, no breakpoint, it typically tells me that the connection was closed by the remote host etc.
The client typically finishes sending the data almost instantly, even though its a 4mb file.
The receiver spends about 2 minutes reading from the Network Stream, which doesnt make sense, if the client finished sending the data, does that mean the data is just floating in cyber space, and being pulled down?
Surely it should be synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I know where my code was going wrong.
It turns out that the scope I was creating my TCPClient that was doing the sending, was declared and instantiated within a method.

This being the case, the GAC was disposing of it, even though the Receiving Server had not finished downloading the stream.

I managed to resolve it by creating a method that can detect when the Client has disconnected on the server end, and until it has actually disconnected, it will keep looping/waiting until disconnected.

This way, we are waiting until the server lets go of us.